# split by \r in a file instead of \n in python

Tags: python, newline

I have a log file with contain both "\n" and "\r\n".

I tried spliting by "\r" and it returns only 1 element. I suspect python might have remove them when reading the file.

Is there a way to only split by "\r\n" as I don't want to split the stacktraces.

Comment: Can you post the method that you have already tried and a sample log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3 and `open` text file you need to inform Python, that you wants keep your newlines untouched following way:

```
open('filename.txt','r',newline='')
```

Otherwise `\r\n` and `\r` and `\n` will be replaced with `\n`

([relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter))